# Not able to create one list of errors per user

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I've created a class called Users() and one of the validations I'd like to make is the password validations, like minimum password length, containing at least one number and so on. The problem comes when I instantiated two users and called the method `check_password`, when I print the result it display only one list with the errors of the two users, instead of one per user. Below the code.

user.py:

```
users = []
class Users:
    error_list = []

    def __init__(self, user_id, user_name, password = '1234'):
        self.__user_id = user_id
        self.__user_name = user_name
        self.__password = password
        users.append({"user_id":self.user_id,"user_name":self.__user_name,"password":self.__password})

    @property
    def user_id(self):
        return self.__user_id

    @property
    def user_name(self):
        return self.__user_name

    @property
    def password(self):
        return self.__password

    def check_password(self):
        if len(self.__password) < 8:
            self.error_list.append({'error_cd': 1,'error_message':'your password must have at least 8 characters'})
            return self.error_list
```

main.py:

```
from user import Users

user1 = Users(1,'Johnny','111')
user2 = Users(2,'Carlos','11111')

print(user1.password)
print(user1.check_password())

print(user2.password)
print(user2.check_password())
```

Executing the main.py the output is:

```
"C:\Users\a0091660\Desktop\Meus arquivos\Pessoal\pyProjects\Pluralsight\roleta_russa\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/a0091660/Desktop/Meus arquivos/Pessoal/pyProjects/Pluralsight/roleta_russa/main.py"
111
[{'error_cd': 1, 'error_message': 'your password must have at least 8 characters'}]
11111
[{'error_cd': 1, 'error_message': 'your password must have at least 8 characters'}, {'error_cd': 1, 'error_message': 'your password must have at least 8 characters'}]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And I want to:

```
"C:\Users\a0091660\Desktop\Meus arquivos\Pessoal\pyProjects\Pluralsight\roleta_russa\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/a0091660/Desktop/Meus arquivos/Pessoal/pyProjects/Pluralsight/roleta_russa/main.py"
111
[{'error_cd': 1, 'error_message': 'your password must have at least 8 characters'}]
11111
[{'error_cd': 1, 'error_message': 'your password must have at least 8 characters'}]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Problem is that `error_list` is class variable, so it's common for all instances of `Users`. Put `error_list = []` inside`__init__`: `self.error_list = []`

Comment: Thank you very much @AndrejKesely! You are right, variable scope problem :)